# Copying into char** from char*

Tags: c

I couldn't think of a better way to phrase the question title, but basically, I'm trying to copy from a sting into a string-pointer (Ideally I wouldn't use pointer-to-pointer but it's an assignment)

As an example, I want to know how to do this:

> strcpy(*string_pointer, string);

But, when I try to, it gives me a segmentation fault.

If this is too vague, I'll post the whole code, though I know for sure that's the one bit that isn't working (debugger and whatnot) and I simply don't know how to do it otherwise. I've tried all "conventional" methods of copying a string, and I know the string is initialized, since if I try to do this:

EDIT: I guess it's just easier to post the code as it currently is.

```
int main(void) 
{
   char* string = "test";
   reverse(&string);
   return 1;
}

void reverse(char** string_pointer)
{
   int i=0, max, y=0;
   max=strlen(*string_pointer);
   char string1[max], string2[max];
   strcpy(string1, *string_pointer);
   for ( y=max-1; y>=0; --y)
   {
         string2[i] = string1[y];
         ++i;
   }
   string2[i]='\0';
   printf("%s\n",string2);  // works until here, printf was to test that
   strcpy(*string_pointer, string);
}
```

Above is the test program I've created to try and figure out a solution without messing around in my main program too much. All variables, declarations and everything else pertaining this particular function are exactly as they are in the main code.

I apologize for not being able to post more than this.

Comment: What are the types of string and string_pointer?

Comment: It sounds like *string_pointer is pointing to an area of memory that you are not permitted to write into. Did you perhaps initialize it by pointing it at a string constant?

Comment: Could you update the question with some more code? I would like to see how you allocate the string you pass as parameter as well as the code you know it is working.

Comment: Yes, you need to provide compilable code that reproduces the problem. It's likely that you aren't setting either the source or the destination to point to memory that is allocated.

Comment: you should have gotten a warning from your compiler at char* string = "test";  "test" is a const char*.  you're converting it to char*, and then later try to write into it.  that's why it crashed.  you're writing to a const char* cast to a char*.

Comment: You problem is that you are trying to write to a const string. I updated my answer to explain that.

Comment: Weirdly enough, there was no warning whatsoever at that. In fact, there were no error messages at all except for the segmentation fault. Changing to a strcpy(string, "test"); made the entire code work just fine. I'm now aghast that I've been beating my head against the wall for a good day trying to figure out what was wrong. Gawd.

Anywho, I really appreciate all messages/answers/comments to this question. If I'd known this website was so awesome and effective, I'd have started using it a lot sooner.

Comment: C++ avoids this problem by forbidding assignment of a string literal to a `char *`, you need to use a `const char *` for that. I don't know why plain C still allows this.

Comment: String literal in C is not `const` qualified so you won't get any warning or compile error. However, if you attempt to change it, then it will lead to undefined behaviour and likely segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure `string_pointer` points to a valid `char *`.

```
char array[20];
char **string_pointer = &array;
char *string = "str";

strcpy(*string_pointer, string);
```

The code above works because `string_pointer` points to the start of a array of char, which can be target of a `strcpy`, and there is enough room there to receive the copy.

Your problem after all is that you are trying to write to a constant string. Try changing main to:

```
int main(void) 
{
   char string[] = "test";
   reverse(&string);
   return 1;
}
```

and it should work.

With this change, the memory space for string will be allocated on the stack. The way you had it, the string was allocated by the compiler in a read-only area of the executable.

P.S. You don't need to make a copy of the string to reverse it, it is possible (and more efficient) just to loop over the string itself, stopping at half its length.

Answer (score 0):

Is there enough room in string_pointer. The problem is that you get segfault because the process is trying to write to memory that it does not have access to.

use strncpy to be safe also, and do sanity checks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your last `strcpy` statement in your `reverse` function. A string literal in `C` is not `const` qualified so attempting to overwrite it won't give any warning or compile error. However, doing so leads to undefined behaviour and most likely segmentation fault. You should either dynamically allocate a `char` buffer in `reverse` and then return a pointer to it to `main` and `free` it after use, or pass a `char` buffer allocated in `main` to `reverse`.

The prototype of standard library function `strcpy` is

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

`dest` must be large enough to receive the copy. Also note that `strcpy` copies the terminating null byte from the `src` to `dest`, so your `dest` must accommodate for this.

```
void reverse(char **string_pointer, char strbuf[]);

// in main function
// C99 variable-length array, +1 for accommodating the terminating null byte

char *string = "test";
char strbuf[strlen(string) + 1]

reverse(&string, strbuf);
```

Or you can also do

```
char *reverse(char **string_pointer);

// in reverse function

char *string2 = malloc(strlen(*string_pointer) + 1);
// do stuff
return string2;

// in main

char *string = "test";
char *reversed_string = reverse(&string);

// do stuff

free(reversed_string);
```